# Select previous record with multiple conditions in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This one's been tricky to quantify, so I may not have this question worded properly first time around.

I have a table following a format similar to this:

```
| id | other_id | timestamp  |
|  1 |        1 | 2012-01-01 |
|  2 |        1 | 2012-01-02 |
|  3 |        2 | 2012-01-02 |
```

What I am attempting to do is, given the record with 'id' 2, and similar records, for which the 'id' column value is known and is unique and the 'other_id' is known corresponding with it, how do I find, for each, the 'id' of the record having the same 'other_id' but the first lower 'id' than the one I already know.

E.g.

```
$arrKnownIds = array (
 0 => array('id'=>2,'other_id'=>1),
 1 => array('id'=>3,'other_id'=>2)
);
```

With this info, I'd like to run a query such that this results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $arrPreviousIds[$row['other_id']] = $row['id'];
 // having in this case values of:
 // $row['other_id'] = 2;
 // $row['id'] = 1;
}
```

I can't quite work out if I need to tackle this using UNION, multiple php query statements or if there's another way.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this one are greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

**Edit** - The original query takes the following form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`other_id`), MAX(`id`), MAX(`timestamp`)
FROM `event`
GROUP BY `other_id`
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `other_id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

// This is intended to get the last 10 unique events and find when they occurred.

// From this, I then try to find when they previously occurred.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you want. Given id 2 it should return id 1 because it is the highest id less than 2 with other_id = 1. Is that correct? So, given id 3 should it return null as there is no lower id with other_id = 2?

Comment: @nnichols, Yes - that's exactly correct as you described it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT t1.id, (SELECT id
               FROM tbl t2
               WHERE t2.other_id = t1.other_id
               AND t2.id < t1.id
               ORDER BY t2.id DESC
               LIMIT 1)
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t1.id IN (1,2,3)
```

There are more efficient ways of doing this if you will be dealing with large result sets. Can you explain exactly how you will be using this query?

**UPDATE** - based on addition of existing query to question here is an updated query to combine the two -

```
SELECT tmp.*, (SELECT `timestamp`
               FROM `event`
               WHERE `event`.`other_id` = `tmp`.`other_id`
               AND `event`.`id` < `tmp`.`id`
               ORDER BY `event`.`id` DESC
               LIMIT 1) AS `prev_timestamp`
FROM (
    SELECT `other_id`, MAX(`id`) AS `id`, MAX(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp`
    FROM `event`
    GROUP BY `other_id`
    ORDER BY `id` DESC, `other_id` ASC
    LIMIT 0, 10
) tmp
```

I have not tried this but it should give the desired result.

Comment: Yup, what I'm doing is looking for specific events being recorded at specific times, which populates the first array, and then looking back in time to see when that event previously occurred, so I can indicate for each separate event the time between them. Each event has a different ID and the time period is what's being used to tell where to find the first match. Based on that, find the previous match.

Comment: In this case the result set is of the order of 10-100, but the data set to search is of the order of 10M, so I didn't want to hit the database 100 times in the worst case (or 10 for that matter), but the IN syntax is perfectly doable in this situation.

Comment: This should work for you then but you should be able to get the whole result in one query. Maybe you should add your existing query to your question. From what you have said I am assuming that you would run one query and then pass the ids from that into this query. If that is the case it can certainly be combined into one query.

Comment: Original query has been added above :)

Comment: Very interesting :) thank you - and educational. I didn't realise that kind of structure would work.  I shall give it a try but this is very clear.